# SQL Server : two columns with the same row values in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a huge dataset with about 400,000 rows. I want to select only the rows where the value of the second column (`val`) exists in the third column (`ecr`) in the same table.

For example, in the sample screenshot shown below, the value of the column `val` on the second row (**4294939057**) is equal to third row value of column `ecr`.

I tried with the following query but it doesn't seem to give the correct rows.

Any tips would be very much appreciated.

```
use dbTest

select val, ecr 
from tableTest 
group by val 
having COUNT (val) > 1
```

I am using SQL Server 2008.

[image]

Comment: do you have a primary key column on this table?

Answer (score 3):

You should use a self join  (could be you need  proper separated index on val and ecr due the dimension of your table  )

```
select a.*, b.* 
from tableTest as a 
  inner join tableTest as b  
    on a.val  = b.ecr
```

Comment: @DestaHaileselassieHagos change `where` to `on`

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want the full output from an inner join, you could use something like this:

```
select *
from tableTest as t
where exists (
  select 1 
  from tableTest as i  
  where t.val  = i.ecr
  )
```

Comment: This is the better solution, because it does not multiply the number of rows.

Comment: This is actually better where you don't have to show all the output of the inner join.

Comment: @sqlzim, But why `select 1`?

Comment: @DestaHaileselassieHagos There is no **runtime** performance difference between `select 1` and `select *` when using `exists()`. Although using `select 1` will avoid having to examine any unneeded metadata for that table during query compilation. 
[EXISTS Subqueries: SELECT 1 vs. SELECT * - Conor Cunningham](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/conor/exists-subqueries-select-1-vs-select/)

Answer (score 1):

The other option besides the join is a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableTest
WHERE val IN (SELECT ecr FROM tableTest)
```